# How do I send locally stored sticker to an inlinequery in Telegram with python-telegram-bot

Tags: python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

Using `https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/inlinebot.py`
is it possible to change this bot to send a local webp (sticker) file as a response to an inline query?

Secondary, what would be the most convenient work around if this is not possible?

**Version of Python, python-telegram-bot & dependencies:**

`$ python -m telegram`

```
python-telegram-bot 8.1.1
certifi 2017.07.27.1
future 0.16.0
Python 3.5.2 (default, Sep 10 2016, 08:21:44)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `send_sticker(some_id, open("local_sticker.webp", "rb"))` to send it to yourself, and get the `file_id`, then use `InlineQueryCachedSticker` for the inline result.